# how does an inverted page table deal with multiple process accessing the same frame

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I've seen the other posts but none has the same problem, So from my understanding an inverted page table's entry depends on both the process id and virtual page number, in the actual page table if the information of both the process id and virtual page number matches then the index is the physical page number/frame number. my question is what happens when more than 1 process needs that frame/physical memory. you can't store both id or vpn in the same index

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! My guess is that this is one of the reasons that inverted page tables aren't very popular.

One solution could be to append a "shared" bit to each entry and create a hash table for each pid. When a page frame with the "shared" bit set is encountered, the MMU should trigger a fault that will cause the OS to use the pid of the requesting process and the virtual address to index into the hash table. At this point, its the same behavior as the global hash table, where the hashed entry contains the  pairs.

An upside to this is that we can still use the pid field in the page table entry, so 1 of the shared pids will hit.

Some downsides are that the hash table per pid could be the same size as the global hash table, so we effectively increase the size of the global hash table by 2^16 (or however many pids are supported)! Of course, the hash table per pid probably won't be that large, so we could dynamically change the size based on how many entries are in use. But, this has its own side-effects, where we may have to evict other pages whenever we want to increase the size.

I'm sure there are better solutions out there, and I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

Add a "remap" bit to the page table entry. If a page table entry has this "remap" bit set, the given physical address is not the real physical address, instead its the index into the *Remap Table*. The Remap Table is a software-controlled data structure that contains mappings from indices to physical addresses. It is shared by all processes, as a page table entry already has the pid. The size of the Remap Table is dynamic; the Remap Table can reside anywhere in contiguous memory, pointed to by a Remap Table Base Register. The Remap Table Tail Register keeps track of the top of the Remap Table, which can increase or decrease.

When a brand new shared page table entry is created, it should be created as a standard page table entry with pid, physical address and virtual address. When other processes request a page for this shared physical address, they should have a page table entry created with the "remap" bit set, and with the physical address pointing to their remap table entry. Software can determine the remap table entry by searching from the base to the tail for any available entries. If none are found, software should increase the tail pointer, evicting the page residing there, if necessary. This remap table entry should contain the physical address of the shared page.

When removing a shared page table, software should remove the remap table entry. If the remap table entry to be removed is at the top of the remap table, software should decrease the Remap Table Pointer to the highest valid entry.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution:

Just create another page frame entry for all of the processes that share that same page table. They should have the pid and virtual address specific to that process, and the same physical page frame number of the shared page. This page table entry should have a "shared" bit that indicates it can be / is being shared with other processes, and that it should be written back to disk when it is evicted. This way, when each process' page table entry is removed, they will each write back the contents of the shared page to disk. This will result in n-1 (n being the number of processes sharing the page) "wasted" write backs, but it avoids the overhead of trying to keep track of all of the processes sharing a page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to map only one virtual address to shared physical address in page table ,so other virtual address references mapped to same shared physical address will result into page faults.(source-Operating System Principles-Galvin)